# Flutter crash on iOS - io.flutter.1.ui EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, flutter

My Firebase Crashlytics log some crashes only on iOS.

I checked the answer from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63894#issuecomment-675284965 issue and every svg files looks fine.

I have no idea when the error occurs and why.

Crash log:

```
io.flutter.1.ui
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

Crashed: io.flutter.1.ui
0  Flutter                        0x10139b384 (Missed)
1  Flutter                        0x1011383f0 (Missed)
2  Flutter                        0x1011c4f84 (Missed)
3  Flutter                        0x1011c4e00 (Missed)
4  Flutter                        0x1012e03ac (Missed)
5  App                            0x104191440 Precompiled_Stub_CallAutoScopeNative + 80
6  App                            0x104248554 Precompiled_PictureRecorder__endRecording_16065589_2825 + 52
7  App                            0x104248504 Precompiled_PictureRecorder_endRecording_2824 + 44
8  App                            0x1042c7424 Precompiled_DrawableRoot_toPicture_4974 + 652
9  App                            0x104849bf8 Precompiled_Svg_svgPictureStringDecoder__async_op_26606 + 400
10 App                            0x1041c24f8 Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458_782 + 112
11 App                            0x1041c282c Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458__rootRunUnary_4048458_783 + 580
12 App                            0x104696974 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runUnary_21628 + 204
13 App                            0x1041bfd84 Precompiled__FutureListener_4048458_handleValue_739 + 208
14 App                            0x1048576ac Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_handleValueCallback_26761 + 84
15 App                            0x1041bdbd0 Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_706 + 1148
16 App                            0x1041befec Precompiled__Future_4048458__completeWithValue_4048458_726 + 124
17 App                            0x1046953b0 Precompiled__AsyncAwaitCompleter_4048458_complete_21600 + 424
18 App                            0x1041bc2c4 Precompiled_____completeOnAsyncReturn_4048458_674 + 56
19 App                            0x1048499ec Precompiled_Svg_fromSvgString__async_op_26605 + 440
20 App                            0x1041c24f8 Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458_782 + 112
21 App                            0x1041c282c Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458__rootRunUnary_4048458_783 + 580
22 App                            0x104696974 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runUnary_21628 + 204
23 App                            0x1041bfd84 Precompiled__FutureListener_4048458_handleValue_739 + 208
24 App                            0x1048576ac Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_handleValueCallback_26761 + 84
25 App                            0x1041bdbd0 Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_706 + 1148
26 App                            0x1041befec Precompiled__Future_4048458__completeWithValue_4048458_726 + 124
27 App                            0x1046953b0 Precompiled__AsyncAwaitCompleter_4048458_complete_21600 + 424
28 App                            0x1041bc2c4 Precompiled_____completeOnAsyncReturn_4048458_674 + 56
29 App                            0x104849554 Precompiled_SvgParser_parse__async_op_26601 + 424
30 App                            0x1041c24f8 Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458_782 + 112
31 App                            0x1041c282c Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458__rootRunUnary_4048458_783 + 580
32 App                            0x104696974 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runUnary_21628 + 204
33 App                            0x1041bfd84 Precompiled__FutureListener_4048458_handleValue_739 + 208
34 App                            0x1048576ac Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_handleValueCallback_26761 + 84
35 App                            0x1041bdbd0 Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_706 + 1148
36 App                            0x1041befec Precompiled__Future_4048458__completeWithValue_4048458_726 + 124
37 App                            0x1046953b0 Precompiled__AsyncAwaitCompleter_4048458_complete_21600 + 424
38 App                            0x1041bc2c4 Precompiled_____completeOnAsyncReturn_4048458_674 + 56
39 App                            0x104849328 Precompiled_SvgParserState_parse__async_op_26600 + 916
40 App                            0x1041c24f8 Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458_782 + 112
41 App                            0x1041c282c Precompiled_____rootRunUnary_4048458__rootRunUnary_4048458_783 + 580
42 App                            0x104696974 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runUnary_21628 + 204
43 App                            0x1041bfd84 Precompiled__FutureListener_4048458_handleValue_739 + 208
44 App                            0x1048576ac Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_handleValueCallback_26761 + 84
45 App                            0x1041bdbd0 Precompiled__Future_4048458__propagateToListeners_4048458_706 + 1148
46 App                            0x104854a08 Precompiled__Future_4048458__addListener_4048458__anonymous_closure__26732 + 76
47 App                            0x1041c13d8 Precompiled_____rootRun_4048458_762 + 216
48 App                            0x1041c16a8 Precompiled_____rootRun_4048458__rootRun_4048458_764 + 512
49 App                            0x1046962a0 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_run_21617 + 192
50 App                            0x1046981e4 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_runGuarded_21664 + 52
51 App                            0x104819f44 Precompiled__CustomZone_4048458_bindCallbackGuarded__anonymous_closure__26152 + 76
52 App                            0x1041c22fc Precompiled_____microtaskLoop_4048458_779 + 120
53 App                            0x1041c3648 Precompiled_____startMicrotaskLoop_4048458_795 + 40
54 App                            0x1041c3748 Precompiled_____startMicrotaskLoop_4048458__startMicrotaskLoop_4048458_796 + 92
55 App                            0x10419123c Precompiled_Stub_InvokeDartCode + 268
56 Flutter                        0x1012cbfc4 (Missed)
57 Flutter                        0x1013ab680 (Missed)
58 Flutter                        0x101136adc (Missed)
59 Flutter                        0x100e65c08 (Missed)
60 Flutter                        0x100e676b8 (Missed)
61 CoreFoundation                 0x1a4a8da30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
62 CoreFoundation                 0x1a4a8d634 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1004
63 CoreFoundation                 0x1a4a8cb14 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 324
64 CoreFoundation                 0x1a4a86eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1912
65 CoreFoundation                 0x1a4a86200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
66 Flutter                        0x100e67594 (Missed)
67 Flutter                        0x100e66f60 (Missed)
68 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ea3eeb70 _pthread_start + 288
69 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ea3f3880 thread_start + 8
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the problem?

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

I don't have more details.

Comment: Are there any hidden image tag in an svg export?

Comment: @Ashok I didn't notice anything like that.